# Pólya's urn - Probability of drawing two same-colour balls in succession

Tags: probability-theory, polya-urn-model

Pólya's urn is a statistical model which uses the following scheme: there is an urn containing n black balls and m white balls. When a ball is drawn, it is then returned with an additional ball of the same colour.

If there are n black balls and m white balls, what is the probability that k black balls are drawn in succession?

I'd know how to calculate the probability for getting exactly k black balls (not necessarity in succession though) in n trials, but what if I got some before I got the two in succession? How can I model that?

I'm stuck so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What happens if you manually calculate the probability for $k \in \{2,3,4\}$,  performing each manual calculation in succession?  Do you see a pattern?  I am (**perhaps wrongly**) interpreting the problem to be that if, at a given point, there are $(n)$ black balls and $(m)$ white balls, what is the probability that **the next** $(k)$ balls drawn are black.  If I am misinterpreting the problem, please advise.

Comment: Well, I was interpreting the problem to be as follows: if you start with n black balls and m white balls, what is the probability that k black balls are drawn in succession at any given point?

Comment: I was afraid that you were going to say that.  That seems like a much tougher problem.

Comment: I know... I've been trying to crack it for a couple of days now

Comment: where did the problem come from

Comment: My professor sent it